# Base class's function pointer points to child class's member function?

Tags: c++, inheritance, function-pointers

I know it sounds awefully confusing, I have a base template class which has a function pointer, a child class(which is no longer a template class) needs to use that function pointer to point to a child class's member function, and I get all kinds of errors.. Did I violate some universal law of C++?
here is the pseudo code:

```
template <class T>
class Base{
    public:
       typedef void (Base<T>::*fptr) (char in);
       void funcA(fptr FuncToCall){
                 FuncToCall('a');
       }
       ...
    };

class Child:public Base<char>{
   public: 
       void funcToCall(){...}
       void funcB(){
          funcA(funcToCall);
       }
}
```

Here is the error message I got:

> error C2664: 'Base< T >::funcA' : cannot
>   convert parameter 1 from 'void
>   (__thiscall Child::* )(char)' to 'void
>   (__thiscall Base< T >::* )(char)'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code is invalid.

Firstly, in C++ to create a pointer to a member function you *always* have to use operator `&` and a qualified-name of the member, which means that your call to `funcA` should look as follows

```
funcA(&Child::funcToCall); // close, but not yet, see "secondly"
```

Secondly, member pointers are *contravariant*. If want to initialize a base-member pointer object with a derived-member pointer value, you have to use an explicit `static_cast`

```
funcA(static_cast<fptr>(&Child::funcToCall));
```

Note that this is a valid, but potentially unsafe conversion, since it is now your responsibility to ensure that the actual object used on the left-hand side of the call (see "thirdly") has that member.

Thirdly, in order to call a function through such a pointer, you have to supply a concrete object on the left-hand side, so the call in `funcA` should look as follows (I assume that you want to call it for `*this` object)

```
(this->*FuncToCall)('a');
```

Fourthly, your `funcToCall` is supposed to have a parameter. Where is it?

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, i get this error: (similar to the first one)

error C2664: 'Base< T >::funcA' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'void (__thiscall Child::fptr )(char)' to 'void (__thiscall Base< T >::* )(char)'

Comment: @Yonk: Please, pay attention. Either you forgot to add `static_cast`, as shown in my "secondly", or you are compiling a different code.

Comment: Yeah, I added that in, still get a similar error. the only difference is that Child::* became Child::fptr

Comment: @Yonk: That means that you changed the code from the original version. I'm not telepathic, I don't know what else you've done to it. Your *original* code with my modifications compiles and works fine.